# SignalR proper script placement

Tags: javascript, signalr

ok so I decided to post another question (separate from my other one/edited it. this one is more on ordering of scripts).

So my problem is this: I have this at the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>
```

then at the bottom  I got:

```
<script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--Add script to update the page and send messages.--> 

  
</form>
```

Problem is I don't know where to correctly place the scripts/proper ordering placing signalR at the very bottom removes my Navbar/animations/transitions which is in  scripts.js,
placing the signalR above it will fix the Navbar issue but the signalR will stop working.

Comment: also noticed that having the SignalR at the bottom, (meaning working signalR, will also affect my modal/dialogbox i.e dialog box no longer shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I see is that you have 2 different versions of jQuery loaded.

At the top -

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

At the bottom -

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
```

You should only have 1 version. This is probably causing most of your issues. You may have some other conflicts running both bootstrap and jquery-ui (not validated) if similar js/css is applied between both. You may want to search for conflicts and see what impacts you.

As far as order goes load:

1. jQuery-x.x.x.min.js
2. bootstrap.min.js
3. jquery-ui.js
4. signalR-2.1.2.min.js
5. signalr/hubs

Comment: thank you!! will definitely try this one, for now  what I did was added jQuery.noConflict();, before the modal show. as for the bootstrap + jquery UI I was using it for modal and dialog box(acting as custom confirm box) As for the navbar missing, it is in the <script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script> in which it adds/removes class to the body, so what I did was I added it manually to the body class = "" and now have my navbar back.

Comment: You should at minimum only load 1 version of jQuery. I would move your app.min.js after jquery script.